# Rounding a number upto three decimals along with zeros in Excel in C# using interop

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I am working on a C# application which export a datagrid view to an excel file using interop library. I was succesfully able to export the the data expect that I am not able wound a column values to three decimals with zeroes appended at the end if there are only two decimals using the following

```
string volumeIndex = "H" + (dataGridViewIndex.Rows.Count + 9).ToString();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range numberFormatRange;
                numberFormatRange = indexWorkSheet.get_Range("H10", volumeIndex);
                numberFormatRange.NumberFormat="#.###";
```

Not sure if I did it the right way.

**Is there a better way I could solve this?**

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how I've been doing it. Don't forget to Marshal.ReleaseComObject(numberFormatRange) when you're done with it.